# MAMP could not lookup up localhost. Website unavailable

Tags: wordpress, macos, apache, sockets, mamp

A weird error appeared that all of a sudden http://localhost:8888/... is not available. A day ago it worked perfectly fine and now I get this error although I have not installed any software, nor updated MAMP nor updated my Operating System. I have been researching all day of what could be the problem and found several answers which solved other people's problem but sadly not mine. The question is: How can I get my localhost working again?

Once I enter the IP (http://127.0.0.1:8888) the website loads, however, all my links use http://localhost:8888, which means I would have to change all the links to use the IP. There are scripts that do so, but I really want to understand the background and find the root of this problem. I have tried several things:

- Changing the Apache ports to another number which can be done under MAMP Preferences. I get the same error no matter which port I change it to.
- Editing my `etc/hosts` file in order to link 127.0.0.1 to localhost, which I really did not have to do since the code was already there. After I have done this, I opened my terminal and entered  `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` in order to flush the DNS Cache. Afterwards, I restarted my computer and annoyingly the error keeps appearing. Somehow, localhost is not linked to 127.0.0.1, which I think is comparable to when the domain name of a website is not connected to the server IP which can be configured with the Nameservers. This brings me to my third point and last point.
- I looked deeper into the location and opened the "*httpd.conf*"  file found under the path "*etc/apache2/httpd.conf*" where I can configure the Apache HTTP Server. I searched for any ServerName and the only code that appears is some comments describing it. This includes `#ServerName www.example.com:80` and a short description before. I've tried adding a new ServerName as `ServerName localhost:8888` and even simply `ServerName localhost`, still nothing happens.

I've tried other obvious things which are not worthy mentioning for. This seems to me either something really complex to which my knowledge does not reach or something very silly I missed out.

For the record, the `etc/hosts` file contains some weird addresses:

```
##\n# Host Database\n#\n# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface\n# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.\n##\n127.0.0.1 localhost\n255.255.255.255 broadcasthost\n::1 localhost \nfe80::1%lo0 localhost\n\n##SYS##\n127.0.0.1 inst.shoppingate.info\n127.0.0.1 service.shoppingate.info\n127.0.0.1 indexx.org\n127.0.0.1 f.flshbsjs.info\n127.0.0.1 gsy.testersgroupfun.com\n127.0.0.1 sendmessagebox.com\n127.0.0.1 t1.inskinad.com\n127.0.0.1 q.crbfmcjs.info\n127.0.0.1 static.donation-tools.org\n127.0.0.1 istatic.datafastguru.info\n127.0.0.1 static.boostsaves.com\n127.0.0.1 www.best-deals-products.com\n127.0.0.1 fge.solartrendinc.com\n127.0.0.1 nps.pastaleads.com\n127.0.0.1 digitaloptout.com\n127.0.0.1 cdncache-a.akamaihd.net\n127.0.0.1 cdncache1-a.akamaihd.net\n127.0.0.1 rvzr-a.akamaihd.net\n127.0.0.1 rvzr2-a.akamaihd.net\n127.0.0.1 asrv-a.akamaihd.net\n127.0.0.1 cdn.visadd.com\n127.0.0.1 a.visadd.com\n127.0.0.1 ydt.winsurfingclub.com\n127.0.0.1 client.foxydeal.com\n127.0.0.1 s.hklmm.com\n127.0.0.1 i.crbsjs.info\n127.0.0.1 wwm.determineyourroad.com\n127.0.0.1 ext1.engageya.com\n127.0.0.1 ext2.engageya.com\n127.0.0.1 a.tfxiq.com\n127.0.0.1 cdn.staticwebdom.com\n127.0.0.1 api.jollywallet.com\n127.0.0.1 i_crbsjs_info.tlscdn.com\n127.0.0.1 i_flshbsjs_info.tlscdn.com\n127.0.0.1 ppj.qwikbookprint.com\n127.0.0.1 homedesigntreasure.com\n127.0.0.1 www.superfish.com\n127.0.0.1 istatic.eshopcomp.com\n64.251.22.253 shmactustus.com\n64.251.22.253 www.google-analytics.com\n##SYS##
```

I also tried deleting all the remaining addresses leaving only:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

But, after I restart my computer, all the old addresses I previously deleted appear again and the error is still the same. The thing is, this happened all of a sudden overnight and I did not expect this to occur. Does anybody know what is going on? I am open to any suggestions and appreciate your help. Best Regards!!