# Tried EVERYTHING; still "localhost" doesn't resolve

Tags: php, apache, localhost, mamp, osx-yosemite

I have an iMac running Yosemite (10.10.3) and I installed MAMP on it and Apache and MySQL startup fine but I cant get to any page because localhost is not resolving.

I have tried everything, executed every Terminal command I've found, flushed anything flushable, modified/removed/added back all possible combinations in my hosts file, restarted, modified the `ServerName` variable on Mac OS's and MAMP's httpd.conf files and NOTHING fixes it.

Now, the funny part is that ***127.0.0.1*** *(:80 for Mac OS Apache or :8888 for WAMP)* resolves and I get the famous "It works!" and so happens if I try ***my-macs-name.local*** *(:80 for Mac OS Apache or :8888 for WAMP)*.

My hosts file looks like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

The Mac OS Apache httpd.conf file `ServerName` section looks like this:

```
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80
```

WAMP's is like this:

```
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:8888
```

Safari (or any browser) returns:
[image]

Ping to localhost returns:

```
ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host
```

I have gone through every single Stack Overflow, blog, internet tutorial that Google has pointed me to but still cannot fix this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks Safari (or any browser) returns: "Safari Cant find the Server"
Ping returns: "ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host"

Comment: Open Terminal App and run `nslookup localhost`, what is the response?

Comment: @Twisty
`Server:  192.168.1.1`  
`Address: 192.168.1.1`  
`Name: localhost`  
`Address: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Might be a cache issue in Safari. Try deleting your cache. Your OS is resolving the host name to the right IP so it should work fine. Could try changing the conf files to use `*:80` versus `localhost:80`

Comment: @Twisty I don't think it is a browser cache issue, I'm getting the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome as well.

Comment: This person is having the same problem, but so far no replies either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066427/mamp-could-not-lookup-up-localhost-website-unavailable?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

7 years later, I had this exact issue. Turns out it can't resolve ::1 in the terminal for me. It was trying to resolve localhost to that instead of 127.0.0.1 (which was also specified, I guess IPv6 took precedence). Removing ::1 from /etc/hosts solved the issue for me so looks like there's some issue with IPv6 adressess.